# Can't log in whit GDM

Tags: 13.04, gnome, login-screen

I have installed Ubuntu gnome. I restarted it and all went fine. The next day, when i tried to turn on my computer, it appeared the load session screen, and, once i have logged in, it just stayed like that. I mean: the screen says: User: Logged in correctly. That's all. I cant do anything, and when i press Esc, it shows: [screen shoot. Yes, It's in spanish](http://i42.tinypic.com/28rcyeb.jpg).
   This happens me often, but sometimes it doesn't. It seems like it has passed trough that, but suddenly it shows the same screen, but with the warning: Failed to load session "gnome".

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how to resolve this but you may consider using lightdm.
If you can't login using gdm, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to [switch to console mode](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg24t8.htm).

Then install lightdm:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Make it the default login manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```